# Tag synonyms: xattr vs. extended-attributes

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I wanted to search for questions on extended attributes, then I found that there seem to be at least two tags: [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) and [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes).

The mentioned tags seem to refer to the same topic, but they are not aliased.

Should `extended-attributes` be an alias for `xattr`? The latter seems to be used (much) more frequently. Or should this be streamlined in a different way?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me -- retag the extended-attributes Qs to xattr, then make it a synonym of xattr.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've now retagged  the extended-attributes Qs to xattr — peer review is pending. However, for creating a tag synonym I'm lacking the required privilege.

Comment: I think I approved most of them; don't forget to look for other improvements (tags, grammar, formatting, etc) in posts as you're editing.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Of course. I'll do my best. Will you care for creating the tag synonym?

Comment: I don't think these should be synonyms; `xattr` is a tool and "extended attributes" is a concept and filesystem feature that is accessed many ways, mostly not through that particular tool. It would be better to separate them and have the excerpts be clear on which to use. It's reasonable for somebody to have expertise on the tool, but not the general concept, and vice-versa.

Comment: @MichaelHomer, I agree.  You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think these should be synonyms. `xattr` is [a specific tool](https://github.com/xattr/xattr), provided out-of-the-box on some platforms, and "extended attributes" is a concept and filesystem feature that is accessed many ways, mostly not through that particular tool. It's unfortunate that there's a collision, but there's a clear disambiguation to be made.

It would be better to separate the tags and have the excerpts be clear on which to use. [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) is a not a good name for the extended-attributes tag in any case - it's an incomprehensible abbreviation if you just knew "extended attributes" were what you were looking for - and if they were to be unified, it should be in the other direction.

It's reasonable for somebody to have expertise on the tool, but not the general concept, or to be searching for questions about one in particular, and vice-versa.

I propose [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) for the `xattr` tool, and [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes) for the feature. To that end:

1. [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) should be renamed to [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes) (regardless of whether they are merged or not).
2. A new [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) is created for the tool, and relevant questions are re-tagged with it (possibly in addition to [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes), possibly instead).
3. The excerpt for [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr) should state "This tag is for questions about the `xattr` command-line tool. For questions about extended attributes in general, use [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes).".
4. For [extended-attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extended-attributes), perhaps it could be omitted from the excerpt and only in the wiki, but somewhere at least: "For questions about the use of the `xattr` command-line tool, [also?] use [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xattr).".

Comment: xattr is not just that one tool: it's the name used in system calls, kernel structs etc. in at least [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listxattr.2.html) and [macOS/Darwin](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/listxattr.2.html).

Comment: Agreed, though many questions about those things are off-topic. It doesn't have another name and the broader concept does.

Comment: Any consideration for making the tag for the tool `xattr-tool`, or something more descriptive than just `xattr` to make it very clear that the tag is not referring to extended attributes in general?

Comment: And the end result of all of this was there is no tag for `xattr`, and there is no tag for `extended-attributes`? Wow,